# Blazor WASM application (Client, Server, Shared) takes long to publish

Tags: blazor, webassembly, .net-7.0

I have a Blazor WASM application and every time I try to publish the application it takes just under 15min which I think cannot be correct.

I have realize that when I change something on the server application the publishing of the app is a lot quicker, as soon as I change something on the client side the publishing takes 14-15min.

Is there any reason why this will happen?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and disabling trimming solved it:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
  <WarningsAsErrors>$(WarningsAsErrors);NU1605;RZ2012</WarningsAsErrors>
  <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
  <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed> <!--This line here-->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: How much bigger is that compared to fully trimmed?

Comment: You will have to test it yourself as it will be different for every codebase.